# (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Disk [public] does not have a configured driver Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, voyager

I'm getting this error when I uploaded my project on a centos server
`(InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Disk [public] does not have a configured driver`

Everything is correct in filesystem.php:

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
          
        'public' => [
           'driver' => 'local',
           'root' =>  public_path('storage'),
           'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
           'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and in voyager.php :

```
'storage' => [
        'disk' => 'public',
    ],
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is the first time it is being uploaded to your CentOS server ? If not try running `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti , it was working before but not uploading pictures to the right path, I kept checking the dashboard and the logo of voyager was still moving around as loading and then it stopped with this error and I cant get to the dashboard again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded the same config files to the server, literally with no change and it worked...